# Recursive extracting of tree structure of included text file documents from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

I often find myself needing this:

Say you have a `test.c` file; it includes other files, say:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"
#include "../mylib_extra.h"
#include "../mylib_bonus.h"
...
```

... then, say, "mylib.h" in the same directory, loads also something else:

```
#include <special.h>
#include "/path/to/calculator.h"
#include "testing/tester.h"
...
```

... etc. Now, some of these statements refer to system directories, which one must know beforehand - but in principle, I guess it would be possible to write a tool, which given a pattern of the "include" statement, could recursively open all files referred to in the initial file, look for the same statements there, open files further - until it draws a tree map. Items it couldn't open without a knowledge of the path, would be marked.

I would imagine a tool like that working like this (where files found/opened are marked with a (*), and no markings otherwise)

```
$ ./getincludetree test.c

test.c
- <stdio.h> 
- "mylib.h" (*)
-- <special.h> 
-- "/path/to/calculator.h" (*)
--- ...
-- "testing/tester.h" (*)
--- ...
- "../mylib_extra.h" (*)
-- ...
- "../mylib_bonus.h" (*)
-- ...
```

Even better, if you could specify a pattern for the include statement, then instead of `#include "..."`, one could use, say `\input{...}` and use the same tool for finding the include structure of a Latex document, as well.

Is there anything like that out there?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Are you looking for a Makefile or something like that? I don't really get the problem?

Comment: @Bernhard - not a makefile, a command-line tool that can work under Linux (edited tags); I was just wandering if there are any existing command line programs which can do the above... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement an autoloader class, a file scanner with caching: http://anthonybush.com/projects/autoloader/source/.

Comment: Thanks for that, @David - I was thinking more of something like a ready-made command line tool; this looks like it will need some coding to implement.. Great resource, though - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Seems like you want:

```
Cscope
Ctags
Gnu global
```

Google those names, think that should help you. They are source indexers.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @chiggsy - looks like "source indexer" is what I was looking for - will report back once I get around to it. Cheers!